# Winsock error codes 10054 and 10053

Tags: tcplistener

I have an application that is listening for data received from GPRS units in the field on a normal TCP connection. I'm getting Winsock 10054 and 10053 errors.

As explained by microsoft

10053 : Software caused connection abort. An established connection was aborted by the  software in your host machine, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.

and

10054 : Connection reset by peer. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt (Windows Sockets) for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket.) This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

I'm not sure how to interpret this. How do I determine if the error is caused on the server or by the client sending the information?